# Segmentation Fault when using isql for ODBC connection to Progress Openedge database 10.2B

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, odbc, openedge, isql

OS: Red Hat 4.1.2-54

```
Linux 2.6.18-92.el5 #1 SMP Tue Jun 10 18:49:47 EDT 2008 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Progress OpenEdge Database Release 10.2B on Linux 32 bit

ODBC Driver: `pgoe1023.so` (which was available with the database package)

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/dlc/odbc/lib:/usr/dlc/lib

export ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini

isql -v Progress
```

---

I am receiving "Segmentation fault" error when trying to use ODBC connection to progress database using `isql` command.

I have followed the required steps mentioned in [this article](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P191281) and installed missing library `libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3` (with `yum install compat-libstdc++-296.i386`).

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any indication in the kbase article, nor in your post, that a db is running and accepting SQL connections.  The kbase is assuming "testdb", port 5555 and a user named "sysprogress" (password "sysprogress" too).

Assuming that you have a "testdb" and that you setup the user you  also need to start a server to accept SQL connections.  For instance:

```
proserve testdb -m3 -Ma 5 -Mpb 5 -S 5555 -ServerType SQL -minport 9000 -maxport 9100
```

Before you try to use it with your isql stuff you can test that this is working with Progress' "sqlexp" command:

```
sqlexp -user sysprogress -password sysprogress -db testdb -S 5555
```

If that doesn't work then you have not correctly configured the db to  accept SQL connections and downstream utilities, like isql, will not work.